# Flask update divs created using a for loop using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, flask

I am generating some bootstrap cards using for loop on my flask template. On each card, there is a button which runs an ajax query. What  I want to do is show the content retrieved on the card body. The ids of the card body are dynamic since I am generating them via a for loop.

```html
      <div>
        <h5 id="resultHeader">Results - Men</h5>
        <div class="row">
          {% for gen in ev_list %}
            {% for evt in gen.boys %}
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card result_card">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    {{ evt }}
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary evt float-right" data-event="{{ evt }}" data-id="{{ meet.meetid }}" data-gender="-men">
                      <i class="fas fa-file-download"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text" id="result_{{ evt }}">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}          
        </div>
      </div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.evt').on('click', function() {
        var event = $(this).attr('data-event');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var gender = $(this).attr('data-gender');


        var p_text = $('#result_'+$(this).attr('data-event')).text();
        console.log('#result_'+$(this).attr('data-event'));
        console.log(p_text);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/process',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "event" : event, "meetid":id, "gender":gender} ),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#result_'+$(this).attr('data-event')).text(data);
        });
    });
```

The html on the browser looks as follows:

[image: html of for loop]

The console output on the browser from the js script is as follows:

[image: console output]

Although the id of the P tag and the id that I am targeting looks similar it seems that the correct element is not picked up by jquery. How can I fix this?

Comment: tried $("[id='result_'+event]").text(data); Did not pickup the element correctly. What is the correct flask syntax to handle this issue?

Comment: This is all javascript, so: `$("[id='result_'" + event + "']").text(data);`

Comment: ```$("[id='result_" + event + "']").text(data);``` had to remove the extra single quote to get it working. Thanks for the help